# How do I find out what font my X server is using?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, fonts

I want to know what font my X server is currently using.

I'm running Xorg on Arch linux.

Comment: Your X server is not using a font. X cliens may use fonts. Can you state your question in a different way? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Since the current font used by my browser is not displaying unicode characters, I want to know what font Chrome is currently using.

Comment: Ah, that's a much better question! I would propose you  ask it as a new question, because this one will not get out of the downvotes anytime soon. And the new one may get some upvotes, even!

Comment: If you want to do that, copy this question, revert your last edit, and paste it into a new question.

Comment: Your first comment helped me realize that my problem was related with the client (browser) not the X server. Now I fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: No, don't delete because the answer here is pretty good, and can be found by the question.

Answer (score 2):

Though the question is not clear, let's clarify that in the answer, with various ways to list fonts. You can have [server-side fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Font_Server) (deprecated) and client-side fonts.

- The list of available server-side fonts can be obtained with the `xlsfonts` utility.
- Concerning client-side fonts, this depends on the client. Such fonts are generally managed with fontconfig, and you can have a list of *available* fonts with the `fc-list` utility.

AFAIK, there's no standard way to know what fonts a client has been using. Looking at font files opened by the client with the `strace` utility may give you an idea, but remember that you cannot look in the past.